# Django how to filter products by multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a db that contains products(name, origin place, price, img...) and I want to filter them by place or price or both when I chose from form.
My models:

```py
class ProductFilter(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My forms:

```py
class ProductFilterForm(forms.Form):
    place = forms.ChoiceField(choices=place_choices, widget=forms.Select())
    price = forms.ChoiceField(choices=price_choices, widget=forms.Select())

    class Meta:
        model = ProductFilter
        fields = ('place', 'price')
```

with place_choices:

```py
place_choices = (
    ("A", "All"),
    ("C", "Cellphones"), 
    ("M", "Media Mart"), 
    ("N", "Nguyễn Kim")
)
```

price_choices:

```py
price_choices = (
    ("", "All"),
    ("A", "Giá thấp > cao"),
    ("B", "Giá cao > thấp")
)
```

My views right now:

```py
def show_db(request):
    place = ProductPlaceForm()
    newForm = ProductNameForm()
    filterForm = ProductFilterForm()
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    ft_place = request.POST.get('place', None)
    ft_price = request.POST.get('price', None)
    print(ft_place)
    print(ft_price)
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', {'product_list' : product_list, 'form':newForm, 'place':place, 'filterForm':filterForm})
```

My template:

```html
{% block content %}
    {{filterForm}}
    <ul class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap align-content-center justify-content-around align-items-center list-unstyled">
        {% for p in product_list %}
            <li>
                <div class="card h-100 mt-2 border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="{{p.img}}" class="card-img-top" style="height:17.813em;width:auto;" alt="product image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{p.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{p.current_price}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Store: {{p.place}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Add at {{p.date_add}}</p>
                        <a href="{{p.url}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Go to store</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I believe i have to redirect back to the template each time i chose the value i want to filter but i don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a few changes.

1. **models.py**

You should use the `choices` argument and set its value to your respective choices.

```
place_choices = (
    # ("A", "All"),
    ("C", "Cellphones"), 
    ("M", "Media Mart"), 
    ("N", "Nguyễn Kim")
)
price_choices = (
# ("ALL", "All"),
("A", "Giá thấp > cao"),
("B", "Giá cao > thấp")
)
class ProductFilter(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=place_choices) 
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=price_choices)
```

2. **forms.py**

Use `ModelForm` instead of `Form`. It makes it easier to render models as forms.

```
from django import forms
class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Becasue this is a ModelForm, you don't need to redefine the fields of the form to use in a template
    class Meta:
        model = ProductFilter
        fields = "__all__" # Use all fields from the model. It is equal to ['place', 'price']
```

3. **views.py**

Create two view functions: one for rendering the form when a user first visits your page, the other for filtering the model. Please note in the `products_view` that  am making use of `Q` [object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). This is because `Q` object allows using an `OR` operator.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def form_view(request):
    # instantiate the ModelForm
    form = FilterForm()
    # Return the form.html, passing the form into its context
    return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form})

def products_view(request):
    place = request.GET.get("place") # Get the submitted value for place
    price = request.GET.get("price") # Get the submitted value for price
    
    # Use Q object in filtering the queryset
    products = ProductFilter.objects.filter(Q(place=place) | Q(price=price))

    form = FilterForm()
    # Return the products and the form to the form, but include products into its context
    return render(request, "form.html", {"product_list": products, "form": form})
```

4. **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
# Import the views
urlpatterns = [
    path("form/", form_view, name="form"),
    path("products/", products_view, name="products"),
]
```

5. **form.html**

Finally, the template. Make sure the form is inside the `form` HTML tag and add a submit `button` or `input` because Django forms don't do it automatically. In the form's action attribute, reference the view url of `products_view` by using Django's `url` [tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'products' %}" method="get">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Filter products">
    </form>
    <hr>
    {% if product_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for p in product_list %}
            <li>
                <div class="card h-100 mt-2 border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="{{p.img}}" class="card-img-top" style="height:17.813em;width:auto;" alt="product image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{p.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{p.current_price}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Store: {{p.place}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Add at {{p.date_add}}</p>
                        <a href="{{p.url}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Go to store</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>Select some fiters to display results</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This basic setup should be enough to achieve what you need.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply. Your solution solves part of the problem. The filter by price i want it to sort from low to high or reverse but right now i storing the price in string (because the value is scrape from another site)

Comment: To be able to sort the prices you need to change the price field to a number (probably a `DecimalField`). It doesn't make sense to store prices as strings. My answer was simply to show you how to do it. I hope you can manage to do it on your own.